# Can't Resolve a service using AppHostBase.ResolveService<T> API in ServiceStack 4

Tags: servicestack, funq

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 and attempting to resolve a few services using the example:

```cs
var authService = AppHostBase.Resolve<AuthService>();
authService.RequestContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ToRequestContext();
var response = authService.Authenticate(new Auth
{
    UserName = model.UserName,
    Password = model.Password,
    RememberMe = model.RememberMe
});
```

or I've also tried:

```cs
using (var helloService = AppHostBase.ResolveService<HelloService>())
{
    ViewBag.GreetResult = helloService.Get(name).Result;
    return View();
}
```

In the first case I needed the `RequestContext` injected so I tried that approach and in the second case I was using the example which I understand has the `RequestContext` automatically injected through `Funq`.

`ResolveService` could not be found when I tried the second approach and in the first approach `RequestContext` is not a valid property.  Am I missing something simple or has there been changes to the API?

Comment: Did using `ServiceStackHost.Instance.Resolve` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation does appear to be wrong for this as there is no longer a `ResolveService<T>` on `AppHostBase`. It needs to be updated due to changes in the Api.

You can do this in ServiceStack v4 with MVC:

```cs
var authService = HostContext.Resolve<AuthService>();
...
```

Comment: @Scott or the shorter alias **HostContext.ResolveService<AuthService>()**.

Comment: @mythz Good call, that's easier.

Comment: @Scott yep, also no need to set the Request as it already [uses HttpContext.Current by default](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/HostContext.cs#L322-L328).

Comment: That was great, most of the examples I had seen all used the old API, this is much easier.